# Is GP in breach of any laws or ethical standards by refusing to refer a seriously ill patient for community Intravenous therapy?

Tags: united-kingdom, medical

The NHS GP refuses to refer a seriously ill patient for community intravenous therapy. His reason is that the patient does not meet the criteria, but after speaking to the community intravenous therapy service they say that they don't have any criteria and all that is needed for a patient to get this service is to be referred to them by their GP.

Is the GP and their practice in breach of any laws or ethical standards if they don't refer a seriously ill patient for home intravenous therapy?

Comment: Having looked at several NHS Trust guidance on this, the therapy service may not have eligibility criteria for managing a patient, but GPs and doctors invariably do have eligibility criteria - https://www.nhft.nhs.uk/download.cfm?doc=docm93jijm4n1554#page11 for example.  Its not just a case of “I want X”.

Answer (score -1):

### No

Being wrong doesn't breach ethical or legal requirements.

If being wrong amounts to negligence then the patient might have a claim for damages.